# Tracking Wireless Network Usage

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, bandwidth, wireshark

How do you determine the overall bandwidth usage for each computer connected to a wireless network?

I manage a small wireless network consisting of a couple of cheap Cisco/Linksys wifi routers. Unfortunately, these routers seem to have little built-in logging ability, and no way to tell which clients are using a lot of bandwidth. This is a problem because several dozen people use the wireless, and occasionally the network speed will get extremely slow (`ping google.com` takes several seconds/minutes).

I'm suspecting someone's downloading movies/torrents, which I wouldn't mind so much, but it's interfering with other people doing their jobs. I've already manually caught a couple interns downloading torrents, but I want to be more pro-active about it, and walking around the office to see what everyone's doing isn't practical.

Is there any way for a computer connected to a wireless network to monitor usage associated with MAC/IP addresses? I've looked into software like Wireshark, but it seems insanely complex to configure it to monitor any usage other than your own.

I don't care what sites people are going to, only the overall amount of bandwidth they're using. What's the easiest way to find this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly advise spending the money for a router which has decent traffic monitoring and *Quality of Service* (or "QoS") which will allow you to not just see what and who is using bandwidth, but mark certain types of traffic as high-priority (skype, online multiplayer games, email, webbrowsing, streaming audio/video) or low-priority (http downloads, torrenting, ftp). Most medium / high-end ($70-$120) consumer routers support this, especially if you get one which can run [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com) as a replacement firmware.

You mention interns, which suggests a work environment; The solution might be as simple as informing the employees that bandwidth is limited and that they should avoid and minimize high-bandwidth activities, and that you'll be monitoring the network for overall health. (Note, the definitions of 'high-priority' and 'low-priority' in the first paragraph might also be different, and you might want to outright block certain types of traffic or ports or websites)

Answer (score 1):

Less on the topic of monitoring but if you believe people are using high-bandwidth applications you could just block the ports for them on your firewall. the ports for bit torrent traffic are TCP 6881-6889, 6969 and 8080 and to insure blocking it make sure that UDP 1024-65534 are also blocked. (source: http://www.imfirewall.com/en/protocols/Bittorrent.htm) if you follow a similar approach with all other strenuous applications (skype, gaming etc) you should notice improved network performance.

Comment: Heh, the Linksys's admin interface informs me that 1024-65534 is an invalid UDP range...

Comment: it would probably be best to listen more closely to the other guy.